# Apache document root and VirtualHost

Tags: apache, dns, subdomain, virtualhost

I'm having some problems with setting up a VirtualHost with Apache on CentOS. I'll try my best to explain what happens.

In our httpd.conf file we had to change the Document root, our base is /var/www/mydomain.com but our files is on /var/www/mydomain.com/store2 and when users goto mydomain.com we want them to come directly to mydomain.com/store2

Main config:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/mydomain.com/store2/"
Directory "/var/www/mydomain.com/store2"
```

So, I've added an config file inside conf.d named subdomains.conf and this is the information inside

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin mail@me.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.com/subdomain
    ServerName subdomain.mydomain.com
    ErrorLog logs/subdomain.mydomain.com
    CustomLog logs/subdomain.mydomain.com common
</VirtualHost>
```

When i restart the httpd service and goto mydomain.com I'm transferred to the virtual host root (/var/www/mydomain.com/subdomain) this also happens when i go to subdomain.mydomain.com. Is there something that I'm missing here? Could there be something with the DNS also? I see that mydomain.com and subdomain.mydomain.com points to the same IP-address.

Comment: What you mean by virtual host root?

Comment: virtual host root = DocumentRoot (/var/www/mydomain.com/subdomain) for the virtual host that is specified. If i comment out the VirtualHost and visit mydomain.com I'm transferred to /var/www/mydomain.com/store2/ but if the virtual host is active I'm transferred to /var/www/mydomain.com/subdomain and the same when i go to subdomain.mydomain.com

Comment: Have you modfiy your `/etc/hosts` file?

Comment: Nope. The /etc/hosts folder is empty and so is the /etc/hosts.conf file